# Ultrawebgrid Footer throws error in chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, ultrawebgrid

I have the below code in my application to set visibility to column footer in ultrawebgrid.

```
Ultrawebgrid1.DisplayLayout.ColFootersVisibleDefault = ShowMarginInfo.Yes;
```

This works good in Firefox and IE, but shows null reference error in chrome, Please look into the error and help on this

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
```

Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.RenderDnLvlHTML.ResolveRowLabelStyle(UltraGridRow row) +3
   Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.RenderDnLvlHTML.RenderRowLabelStyleClass(UltraGridRow row) +37
   Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.RenderDnLvlHTML.RenderColumnsFooters(RowsCollection rows) +590